# Python netifaces module says plat-name must be one of "win32," "win-amd64," "win-arm32," or "win-arm64" but says option plat-name not recognized

Tags: python, pip, python-netifaces

So I can't explain it enough in the title, but I could extend the title here. I don't think anyone else has this issue. I found a python script that uses the netifaces module, but I can't get python to install it. This is the log when installing:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:459: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
  warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
running install
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing netifaces.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to netifaces.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to netifaces.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'netifaces.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.mingw_x86_64\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'netifaces' extension
error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
```

Update: even more modules are doing this, including `webview`.

Answer (score 0):

Which `setuptools` are you using?
The package from mingw is the one you should be using as it includes patches for supporting the platform you are running.